# Php force browser download file without redirect

Tags: php

I have this code on http://domain.com/download.php

```
<?php
$remote_direct_link = "http://example.com/path/to/movie.mp4";
$filename = "movie-test.mp4";
$ctype="application/octet-stream";
header("HTTP/1.0 302 Found");
header("Content-Type: ".$ctype);
header("Connection: close");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename=\"".basename($filename).'"');
header("Location: " . $remote_direct_link);
?>
```

When i access domain.com/download.php on browser, i want it to be forced downloaded file movie-test.mp4 with dialog on browser. But unfortunately, it always redirect to http://example.com/path/to/movie.mp4 and play it on browser. How can it do it ? Is there something wrong on my code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems like a really bad idea to download a file from a remote destination and then send it to the client. It gives a lot of overhead data transfer. The client has to wait till you downloaded the file, before you can serve it. Large files take a long time. Also, you have a new issue if the remote destination is unreachable.

That being said, you should pass the contents of the file, instead of redirecting.

```
<?php
$remote_direct_link = "http://example.com/path/to/movie.mp4";
$filename = "movie-test.mp4";
$ctype="application/octet-stream";
header("HTTP/1.0 302 Found");
header("Content-Type: ".$ctype);
header("Connection: close");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename=\"".basename($filename).'"');
echo file_get_contents($remote_direct_link); // instead of redirection
?>
```

But a better and simpler approach would simply be having the file locally. It enables you to serve the file faster and you save half of the data transfer.

```
<?php
$file_contents = file_get_contents('../outside_http/movie.mp4');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"movie-test.mp4\""); 
echo $file_contents;
```

Comment: Hi Repox, My point is to serve file from remote location (because i really dont't want to save 2G-4G from local then serve to client, this will lead high load server and disk full)

Comment: @NguyenThuan, you should consider using a CDN (like S3) for things like this.  This is only going to cause you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The last line in your code redirects the user to the external URL, which causes all your other code to be ignored. Instead, you may want to try using `readfile()` function like;

```
readfile($remote_direct_link);
```

Comment: I' afraid that readfile($remote_direct_link) will also download file (our files normal 4G) to local server. If so, this is bad performance on high load.

Comment: As Repox stated, its already bad aprroach to serve remote file from your script. And there is no way you can force user download a remote file without you having it, unless you redirect the user to the file; however in that case, your headers will be abondoned and the remote files headers will be applied. That was your case which played the file in browser. If you really need to serve a remote file, then your server will need to act like a pipe. `readfile();` will achieve this reading the file into your server's memory and pass it to the client.

Comment: Hi Turab, I try $remote_direct_link with this url https://r5---sn-42u-nbok.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=13d1cbec4e2122a4&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1440143969&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=4F53E5952853A03990BBCF67967B2B444B74E7BA.4827196EE1F2D976475CAC4D01EA27F485656C98&key=lh1&title=test-mp4&ir=1&rr=12 and it works, i really don't know why how it works, it's strange ?

Comment: It's because that server sends you the header for downloading rather than streaming. Remember what I said in the previous comment; you are redirecting the user an external URL which will abondone your headers and the client will receive the header from that remote URL. To sum up; if the external URL you redirect sends a download header, the client will be downloading; or if the external URL streams the file, the client will be watching in the browser no matter what your headers are. It will be completely up to the remote URL's header. So its not your code is working.

Comment: tks for your explanations